# Closed form for $f_k(y)$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, summation, binomial-theorem

The question is quite simple. Given
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+y)^k$$
We can re-write it in terms as a polynomial in $x$, with coefficients being polynomials in $y$, i.e
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+y)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f_k(y)x^k$$
I attempted to re-write it as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{r=0}^{k}{k \choose r}x^{k-r}y^r$$
$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{k}{k \choose r}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^r\right)x^k$$
I tried equating but came back to the original form. Any help/answer would be appreciated

For example: $n= 3$

$$f_0(y) = 1+y+y^2$$
$$f_1(y) = 1+2y$$
$$f_2(y) = 1$$

so we have $(1+y+y^2)x^0+(1+2y)x+(1)x^2$

Comment: Here $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{k}{k \choose r}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^r\right)x^k$$ you do not want the $x$ inside the $r$ sum.

Comment: Yes I know but I can't seem out get it out in a way thats useful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should learn how to do these yourself.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+y)^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} x^j y^{k-j} .
$$
Now, for each $j$ collect all the terms with $x^j$.
(Reverse the order of summation.)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} x^j y^{k-j}=
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=j}^{n-1}\binom{k}{j} x^j y^{k-j} .
$$
The condition $j \le k$ in the first one yields the condition $k \ge j$
in the second one.
Then factor out from the inner sum things that depend only on $j$
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{k=j}^{n-1}\binom{k}{j} y^{k-j}\right)x^j .
$$
In the required notation,
$$
f_j(y) = \sum_{k=j}^{n-1}\binom{k}{j} y^{k-j} ,
\\
f_k(y)= \sum_{i=k}^{n-1}\binom{i}{k} y^{i-k} 
= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{k+j}{k} y^{j} .
$$
We have to keep track of re-named dummy variables.

Comment: Yeah I know it's simple but somehow struggled more than expected on this

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^q]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^q$ of a series. We obtain for $0\leq q\leq n-1$:

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f_q(x)}&=[x^q]\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+y)^k=\sum_{k=q}^{n-1}[x^q](x+y)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=q}^{n-1}\binom{k}{q}y^{k-q}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1-q}\binom{k+q}{q}y^k}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *linearity* of the *coefficient of* operator. We also start the with index $k=q$, since powers of $x$ with power less than $q$ do not contribute.
- In (2) we select from the binomial the coefficient of $x^q$.
- In (3) we shift the index to start with $k=0$.